# Computed multiplication

Tags: webforms, 9

I have a webform where I am using the *Twig Computed* module to calculate an amount. It is simple and straight forward: I have a field that captures the amount and I'm using Twig to multiply it to find the fee; the fee amount is a fixed rate

The Computed Value/Markup is `{{ data['license_amount']|number_format(2) * 0.019 }}`. It works when `data['license_amount']` is lower than 999; it shows a wrong total when `data['license_amount']` is higher than 999.

If the amount is 500 the value is 9.5 as it should.

If the amount is 5000 the value is returned as 0.095

Comment: I agree with the locale part in the comment. Thousands separator seem to play you tricks here. However, the only change I'd suggest in the case is to add the second(decimal_point) and third(thousand_sep) parameters as explained in twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html and this should be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should drop the `number_format` altogether (not sure what the requirement is), or place it at the end of the calculation, i.e.

`{{ (data['license_amount'] * 0.019)|number_format(2) }}`

`number_format` is a wrapper around PHP's number_format function

From PHP's documentation page:

```
// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56
```

It seems like you are running the calculation on something like 5'000 or 5,000 (depending on your locale), which would explain the results you are getting.

Good luck!